# Distinguish tags from fields in InfluxDB "SELECT *" results

Tags: influxql

Assume you're given an InfluxDB measurement you haven't seen before and you run,

```
SELECT * FROM measurement
```

How can you tell which of the keys returned are tags, and which are fields? The InfluxDB shell sorts the keys alphabetically, so unlike the Line Protocol, fields don't come before tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can see which is which with

```
show field keys from <measurement>; show tag keys from <measurement>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no indication of which `SELECT` result columns are fields and which are tags, but you can [select all fields separately from tags](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#select-all-fields-from-a-single-measurement) with

```
SELECT *::field FROM <measurement>
```